# Oracle bulk update table from where clause

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have a master (MD_TS_MAST) which contains

- MAST_ID
- ENG_ID
- MS_DATE

Detail (MD_TS_DETAIL) table

- ID
- MD_ID (rel with MAST_ID)
- JOB_FOR
- JOB_TYPE_ID
- ACCOUNT_ID

Below is SQL where it locates the "MD_TS_DETAIL IDs" by eng_id and date range.
 this gets me the details of.
 102038
 102134
 101970
 102244

Then I just need to update the MD_TS_DETAIL table.

```
UPDATE MD_TS_DETAIL
SET JOB_FOR ='25',
         JOB_TYPE_ID ='344',
                      ACCOUNT_ID ='8'

WHERE MD_TS_DETAIL.ID IN (
SELECT D.ID
FROM MD_TS_MAST M
LEFT JOIN MD_TS_DETAIL D ON M.MAST_ID = D.MD_ID WHERE ENG_ID = '621'
AND MS_DATE BETWEEN '02-OCT-14' AND '05-OCT-14';
)
```

This would be converted into a form. But my mind has gone blank on how to update this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like ive had too much coffee.

I added a semi_colon just before the closing bracket (oops). removed and worked fine